# How to avoid scaling of android webview

Tags: android, webview

Is there any way to prevent android webview to scale the rendered web page .
I need to load an url which has links to other pages .When user clicks these links the rendered page is not aligned properly(i mean it cramps all the stuff within the screen width and height ) as compared to default handling of same web page by android browser .

The alignment is proper when i comment shouldOverrideUrlLoading ,but i need the redirects within my app so i can't avoid overriding shouldOverrideUrlLoading.Is there any other options left out.

[image: android webview]

The first image shows webview rendering page within my app as i override shouldOverrideUrlLoading  and the second image shows the same screen after commenting shouldOverrideUrlLoading.

Comment: Are you sure this is an issue of scaling and not CSS?

Answer (score 5):

In the meta tag  try doing this

meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi"

This should stop the android default scaling

Comment: The meta tag `target-densitydpi` has been removed from the **WebKit** specification. You will face problems on **JellyBean** devices. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592015/support-for-target-densitydpi-is-removed-from-webkit) or this [blog post](http://petelepage.com/blog/2013/02/viewport-target-densitydpi-support-is-being-deprecated/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
webview1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
webview1.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
webview1.setInitialScale(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need some scaling, this for instance will scale the page to 50% of its original size in the webview :

```
wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
wv.setInitialScale(50);
```

Comment: thanks sephy ,but setInitialScale has no effect .i am still wondering about the reason.I see no problem with css hence it loads perfectly in Android browser.