# Is there an alternative way to make target-density dpi work in Android 4.4 webview? (Phonegap)

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I recently came across this issue in phonegap cross platform applications that **target-density dpi is no longer supported in Android 4.4** and it is creating severe problems to my existing applications in terms of layouts.

The phonegap application with the following meta information having **target-densitydpi=device-dpi**, the layout comes perfectly in venue 7 running android 4.3

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-     scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

When the same was deployed to venue 8 running android 4.4, the console throws a warning telling target-density dpi not supported. Also the layout goes off the screen.

I confirmed the issue as per [this article](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-fast-canvas/issues/18).

As per my understanding the CSS pixels are not equivalent to the device pixels in this case and hence the issue. And the android team is also requesting for Pixel perfect UI as an alternative

[Link 1 - Viewport target-densitydpi no longer supported](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html)

[Link 2 - Pixel Perfect UI](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/pixelperfect)

I also tried the solution pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968695/adjust-phonegap-app-ui-without-target-densitydpi-device-dpi)

which also didn't give the expected result.

It would be great if there is a way to acheive the property of target-densitydpi=device-dpi through some workarounds. Is there a way?

Comment: any luck in solving this?

Comment: Nope @Audi. I sticked to pixel perfect UI targeting latest platforms.